# cannot read cookies in Notifier Views. Using Ruby 2.3 on Rails 1.86

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, actionmailer

In my send_to_friend view, that corresponds to send_to_friend methos in Notifier.model I access a method that is coded in a helper file. In this method y read a cookie and dependin on the value I show one or other language.
I'm having this error:

undefined method `cookies' for # Notifier:0xc8cda00

Can't I access cookies within Action mailer - notifier views?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can access cookies in a Class that inherits from ActionMailer. Why do you want to access the cookies in a view file?